# Is the killing blow the only thing that determines how much experience I gain from killing an enemy?

Tags: borderlands

I know that killing an enemy on foot will give you more experience than killing an enemy by running them over or shooting them from a vehicle ([related question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/about-vehicles-kills-in-borderlands-and-experience-items-gain)), but is the amount of experience gained dependent solely on the killing blow?

In other words, could I use the vehicle machine guns/rocket launchers to soften up a tough target, get them down to very little death and then pop out of the vehicle to land the killing blow and get the full on-foot XP? Or does it take into account the percentage of damage done on foot/in vehicle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. The XP is given by how you kill the target, not by how you damage it. However, I heard that a patch fixed that, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

It's the killing blow that matters.